# Google cloud Messaging.register gives null pointer error

Tags: android

I implemented client for `Google Cloud Messaging` it gives error 
here

```
regid = gcm.register(PROJECT_NUMBER);
```

is `null pointer exception`

Comment: post some more code and your stacktrace so we can help

Comment: can you post some more code?

Comment: Please check [My Answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533952/getting-null-device-id-while-registering-to-gcm/22534888#22534888)..it might be usefull.

Comment: try {
  regid = gcm.register(PROJECT_NUMBER);//Null Pointer error
  msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;
  Log.i("GCM",  msg);
  }

Comment: i implemented only client side code is it working without server

Answer (score 0):

A little more code would help... How do you retrieve the gcm instance? It expects the ApplicationContext, so if you're doing this in an background thread this would give you a working gcm instance:

```
if (gcm == null) {
    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
}
regid = gcm.register(PROJECT_NUMBER);
```

Answer (score 0):

i also encountered this problem recently on some clients, where i got

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                              at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.register(Unknown Source)
```

finally i could reproduce it on a fresh setup emulator running api level 23. The critical part is when i want to register the sender id.

```
    if (gcm == null) {
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
    }

    String regId = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
```

the gcm object is not null, but when you take a look at the register() method of the GoogleCloudMessaging.class file, the method looks like this:

```
 public synchronized String register(String... senderIds) throws IOException {
    String var2 = this.zzc(senderIds);
    Bundle var3 = new Bundle();
    if(zzaz(this.context).contains(".gsf")) {
        var3.putString("legacy.sender", var2);
        return InstanceID.getInstance(this.context).getToken(var2, "GCM", var3);
    } else {
        var3.putString("sender", var2);
        Intent var4 = this.zzy(var3);
        return zza(var4, "registration_id");
    }
}
```

and here it seems the nullpointer comes from the .contains() check. this seems to be the case if the google play services are not installed on a device. but i am not 100% sure if that is the main cause.

i ended up "fixing" the issue by catching the nullpointer exception on the gcm.register() call and telling the user to install the google play services.

furthermore the register() method is already deprecated, so maybe this issue fixes itself when switching over to using the InstanceID:

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration

https://developers.google.com/instance-id/guides/android-implementation