# Unable to get registration id using GCMRegister

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

The following code is not complete. But contains only relevant code sections which might help in find error. Please notify if additional code sections are required.

I have my AndroidManifest.xml contents as follows

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.priteshvikram.mywhatsapp"
     android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="9"
      android:targetSdkVersion="16" tools:ignore="OldTargetApi"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.priteshvikram.mywhatsapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <permission android:name="com.priteshvikram.mywhatsapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.priteshvikram.mywhatsapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="4323030" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.priteshvikram.mywhatsapp.Login"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.priteshvikram.mywhatsapp.Home"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.priteshvikram.mywhatsapp.ListItemDetails"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/Details"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.priteshvikram.mywhatsapp.Chat"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_chat_window" 
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name=".BroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gcm.intent.RETRY" />
            <category android:name="com.priteshvikram.mywhatsapp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

My Login.java file is as follows

```
    package com.priteshvikram.mywhatsapp;

    public class Login extends Activity {

        String SENDER_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";

        ...

        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    String regid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    context = getApplicationContext();

    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            regid = getRegistrationId(context);

            if (regid.isEmpty()) {
               registerInBackground();
               Log.d("empty"," executing");
            }
        }

        private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
       final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
       String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
       if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
        Log.i("gcm", "Registration not found.");
        return "";
       }
       // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
       // since the existing regID is not guaranteed to work with the new
       // app version.
       int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
       int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
          Log.i("gcm", "App version changed.");
          return "";
       }
       return registrationId;
    }

        private void registerInBackground() {
    Log.d("registerinbackground"," executing");
        new AsyncTask() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
               String msg = "";
               //try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    Log.d("async task"," executing");
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }
                //regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                GCMRegistrar.register(context, SENDER_ID);
                regid = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(context);
                //regid="1";
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;
                Log.d("regid","executing");

                // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP,
                // so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                // The request to your server should be authenticated if your app
                // is using accounts.
                sendRegistrationIdToBackend();
                // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device
                // will send upstream messages to a server that echo back the
                // message using the 'from' address in the message.

                // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
                storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
            //} catch (IOException ex) {
                //msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                // exponential back-off.
                Log.d("error",msg);                 
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to register", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //}
            return msg;
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {
        new SendRegId().execute();
    }

    private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
       final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
       int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        Log.i("gcs", "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
        editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public class SendRegId extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            return downloadUrl(regid);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private Boolean downloadUrl(String reg) throws IOException {
        final String DEBUG_TAG = "XMLData";
        InputStream is = null;
        // Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
        // web page content.
        int len = 500;
        String urlParameters="regid="+reg+"&email="+mEmail;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://priteshvikram-dawud.rhcloud.com/gcm_reg_store.php");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
            conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
            conn.setUseCaches (false);
            // Starts the query
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream ());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();

            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "gcm_reg_store.php response is: " + response);
            is = conn.getInputStream();

            // Convert the InputStream into a string
            String contentAsString = readIt(is, len).replaceFirst("\\s+$", "");
            //Integer.parseInt(contentAsString);
            Log.d("data",contentAsString);
            return true;

        // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
        // finished using it.
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            } 
        }
    }
    public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));        
        String buffer;
        buffer = reader.readLine();
        return buffer;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
    }
}
```

Comment: try [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533952/getting-null-device-id-while-registering-to-gcm/22534888#22534888) to get id...

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the old way of registration with the new way of registration. In the new way you don't use `GCMRegistrar` at all (that class is deprecated). You call `gcm.register(SENDER_ID)`.

```
    private void registerInBackground() {
      Log.d("registerinbackground"," executing");
      new AsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
           String msg = "";
           //try {
            if (gcm == null) {
                Log.d("async task"," executing");
                gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
            }
            regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
```

`GCMRegistrar` registers asynchronously, and that's why `GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(context)` returns null. The whole point of running`registerInBackground()` in the background is to call a blocking registration method that returns the registration ID (which is what `gcm.register(SENDER_ID)` does).