# Not getting registration id from Google cloud messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Some of my devices not getting registration id from google cloud messaging service,while the devices are already registered.I am using the GCMRegistrar(old depricated way) for getting registration Id.

**Note:**And yes GCMRegistrar method is old but still works.Some of my devices getting ids properly wihtout any issue.

Hey techies out there thanks in advance BDW.

Comment: Hello @user3282770, welcome to Stackoverflow! This kind of question is slighty off-topic for this site. Might I recommend you to http://android.stackexchange.com/ for this kind of question? Thank you! :)

Comment: You should include your code if you expect any help (registration code, manifest, intent service).

Comment: use [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533952/getting-null-device-id-while-registering-to-gcm/22534888#22534888) step by step,i hope it will help you.

Comment: @DevCarlsberg:Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user3282770  if that link helps you then you have to upvote man!!