# New Google Cloud Messaging on Android 2.3

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I created an application which use a new library Google Cloud Messaging. Application works fine on newer Android 4.1. But, on android 2.3 don't works, because method register() from GoogleCloudMessaging class don't returns id of device. Do you have any idea how to fix it? 
I will be grateful!

Comment: Is there any error log in your logcat?

Comment: Any message or error from your application? If yes, then please post it.

Comment: Go through my [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533952/getting-null-device-id-while-registering-to-gcm/22534888#22534888),may be it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. In manifest file where is "receiver" I added this

```
<category android:name="com.main.package"/>
```

Without this, older device doesn't get id