# Implementing push notification in android

Tags: android

I am new to push notifications in android so i followed the following tutorial on android developer page.

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

The thing i am not clear is in the intentservice class.It is shown below:

```
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import com.igloo.fragments.sportsfragment;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            /*
             * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM
             * will be extended in the future with new message types, just ignore
             * any message types you're not interested in, or that you don't
             * recognize.
             */
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                        extras.toString());
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {


                //Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                // Post notification of received message.
                sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
                //Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    // Put the message into a notification and post it.
    // This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
    // a GCM message.
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, sportsfragment.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);



        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

The thing that confuses me is the final method:

```
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, DemoActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
        .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

       mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

Can someone please clarify why the pending intent is used here to DemoActivity.class.And also explain what this line does: `mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);`

My understanding is that it takes you to the class where you want to go when i click on the notifciation from the notification bar above.Is it right?
        }

Comment: [Check My Answer Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533952/getting-null-device-id-while-registering-to-gcm/22534888#22534888)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PendingIntent` is set up as a "pointer" and stored by the system so that when the user selects the notification in the status bar the target activity specified in the `notificationIntent` can be called.

If you want to know something more http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/notifications/android-notifications-example/

Comment: So in my case the user will be taken to DemoActivity when the notification in clicked,right?

Comment: Also if i have to pass the notification message to the recieving class , should i put it as a  bundle object in the intent?

Comment: @AchuthanM Yup. Take a look [pilhuhn.blogspot.in/2010/12/pitfall-in-pendingintent-with-solution.html](http://pilhuhn.blogspot.in/2010/12/pitfall-in-pendingintent-with-solution.html)

Comment: SO should i change the flag as mentioned in the article?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67001/discussion-between-m-d-and-achuthan-m).